# how to fix corrupt japanese character encoding

Tags: c#, character-encoding

i have the following string that i know is suppose to be displayed as Japanese text

`25“ú‚¨“¾‚ÈƒAƒ‹ƒeƒBƒƒbƒgƒRƒXƒZƒbƒg‹L”O`

is there any way to decode and re-encode the text so it displays properly? i already tried using shift-jis but it did not produce a readable string.

`string main = "25“ú‚¨“¾‚ÈƒAƒ‹ƒeƒBƒƒbƒgƒRƒXƒZƒbƒg‹L”O.zip";
byte[] mainBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis").GetBytes(main);
string jpn = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis").GetString(mainBytes);`

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the original is Shift-JIS, but you didn't show how you did try. So here is my try to re-code it::

```
string s1 = "25“ú‚¨“¾‚ÈƒAƒ‹ƒeƒBƒƒbƒgƒRƒXƒZƒbƒg‹L”O";
byte[] bs = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(s1);
string s2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetString(bs);
```

And `s2` is now `"25日お得なアルティャbトコスセット記念"`, that looks a lot more like Japanese.

What I assume it that some byte array that represent text Shift-JIS encoded, what read by using a different encoding, maybe Windows-1252. So first I try to get back the original byte array. Then I use the proper encoding to get the correct text.

A few notes about my code:

- 1252 is the numeric ID for Windows-1252, the most usually used-by-mistake encoding. But this is just a guess, you can try with other encodings and see if it makes more sense.
- 932 is de numeric ID for Shift-JIS (you can also use the string name). This is also a guess, but likely right.
- Take into account that using a wrong encoding is not generally a reversible procedure so there may be characters that are lost in the translation.

Comment: thanks rodrigo! that solved my problem! i was using shift-jis to get the bytes instead of Windows-1252. using shift-jis on the bytes produced the proper output. thanks again!